# replacing and adding to a slice of array in python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to make a slice of array and then assign each element of a slice to a number and then update according to indices I provide.

For example:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] --> initial array
```

I want to assign 100 to first two elements i.e

```
a[0:2] = 100 for j in range(0,2)
```

so now the array becomes

```
[100, 100, 0, 0, 0]
```

now if i want to add 100 to the first three elements so the array should now become

```
[200, 200, 100, 0, 0]
```

what's the correct way to do this? I am getting a syntax error for the following code:

```
def arrayManipulation(n, queries):
n = 10
//queries is list of [[starting index, ending index, value to be updated]]
initialArray = [0]*n;
for i in queries:
    firstIndex = i[0]-1
    secondIndex = i[1]
    initialArray[firstIndex:secondIndex] = ((initialArray[j] += i[2]) for j in range(firstIndex, secondIndex))
    print(initialArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate` here It will let you access the `index`s you are interested in and assign values or manipulate them

```
l = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for idx, item in enumerate(l[:2]):
    l[idx] = 100

for idx, item in enumerate(l[:3]):
    l[idx] += 100

print(l)
```

*Note : Initial assignment can be done via (@ShadowRanger)

```
l[:2] = [100] * 2
```

Comment: Note that for simple assignment (rather than mutation), you can do slice assignment more simply/efficiently, e.g. for setting the initial `100`s, `l[:2] = [100]*2`. Bulk mutation (e.g. `l[:3] += 100`) would only work with third party types like `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yep that is correct I do know that, I'm still fresh to programming, I have brief use of some techniques as such that slip my mind when responding but yes, I agree and should have known

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to use `range` and a loop.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0]

for i in range(2):
    a[i] = 100

for i in range(3):
    a[i] += 100

print(a) # [200, 200, 100, 0]
```

Although, it is good to know that Python supports slice assignation.

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0]

a[0:2] = [100, 100]

# To some extent, this even can be done
a[0:3] = map(lambda x: x + 100, a[0:3])

print(a) # [200, 200, 100, 0]
```